# twitter embed size showing small in react native not accepting any styling

Tags: css, react-native, twitter, webview

twitter embed in react native not accepting any custom styling and not getting 100% width

```
if (node.name == "twitter") {
        let JS = '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>';

        let source = JS + '<blockquote style="width: 100% !important; float: left; display: inline-block; backgroundColor: red;" class="twitter-tweet tw-align-center" lang="en"><a style="width: 100% !important; float: left; display: inline-block; backgroundColor: red;" data-width="500" data-height="1000" href="https://twitter.com/anyuser/status/' + node.children[0].data + '"></a></blockquote>';

        return (

            <View style={{ width: vw * 1, height: vh * 0.9, alignItems: 'stretch', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
                <WebView
                    style={[styles, { flex: 1, alignItems: 'stretch' }]}
                    source={{ html: source, baseUrl: 'https://twitter.com'}}
                    javaScriptEnabled={true}
                />

            </View>

        );

    }
```

Check image for more clarification
[showing twitter width problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikk3L.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `scalesPageToFit={false}` for WebView component. Should scale twitter post